# Rewrite curl with node.js request

Tags: node.js, curl

I need to encode the following curl query into a node.js request.
I know that form should do the job but I don't know ho to handle that "payload="

```
curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload={"channel": "#tutorial", "username": "webhookbot", "text": "This is posted to #tutorial and comes from a bot named webhookbot.", "icon_emoji": ":ghost:"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/T5NGB8FE0/B6G57N86A/....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this :

```
request.post({
    url: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/T5NGB8FE0/B6G57N86A/',
    form: {
      payload: '{"channel": "#tutorial", "username": "webhookbot", "text": "This is posted to #tutorial and comes from a bot named webhookbot.", "icon_emoji": ":ghost:"}'
    }
  }, (error, response, body) => {
     //your code
  }
);
```